# convert string arguments to send e-mail can help me please (python)

Tags: python, string, email, arguments

```
import smtplib
import sys
if(len(sys.argv) > 1):
 smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
 smtp.login('gmail.com', 'password')
 de = '@gmail.com'
 para = ['@gmail.com']
 msg2=str(sys.argv[1])
 msg = """From: %s
To: %s
Subject: SMATIJ
server"""+msg2+"""""" % (de, ', '.join(para))
```

i have this error: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting in msg2

```
 smtp.sendmail(de, para, msg)
 smtp.close()
 print "sending message"
```

Comment: Might help to know what arguments you're trying to pass as input. The problem is the last line of your script... the formatting is butchered. Have a look here for some tips -> https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the part thats actually breaking

```
msg = """From: %s
To: %s
Subject: SMATIJ
server"""+msg2+"""""" % (de, ', '.join(para))
```

If we break this up what you are telling python to do is:

```
"""first string %s %s """ +\    # a string of text with 2 placeholders
 msg2 +\                        # a string
 """""" % (de, ', '.join(para)) # empty string of text with no placeholders
                                # (formatted with 2 variables)
```

what you actually want is probably something like this:

```
msg = """From: %s
To: %s
Subject: SMATIJ
server""" % (de, ', '.join(para)) + msg2
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that Python is trying to group your strings like -

```
msg = """From: %s
To: %s
Subject: SMATIJ
server"""+msg2+("""""" % (de, ', '.join(para)))
```

Hence, it trying to apply the strings to the empty strings at the end (not even sure why you need the empty string) , which is causing the issue. You should group the string concatenation together manually. Example -

```
msg = ("""From: %s
To: %s
Subject: SMATIJ
server"""+msg2) % (de, ', '.join(para))
```

Or better yet, use the more powerful `str.format` , Example -

```
msg = """From: {0}
To: {1}
Subject: SMATIJ
server{2}""".format(de, ', '.join(para), msg2)
```

Comment: Thank You very much, this solved my problem. I had a string with placeholders constructed immediately before the " % (tuple)" and got this error which puzzled me entirely. If I just save the constructed string to a variable and use _that_ before the " % (tuple)", everything works without a wince.